# AngularJS UI Grid sorting does not work for nested object

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS UI grid to show my data in grid format. However sorting is not working for the nested object column. For rest of the columns (For non-nested objects) sorting is working fine.
Here is the code snippets.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>
    Angularjs UI-Grid Sorting Example
    </title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("uigridApp", ["ui.grid"]);
    app.controller("uigridCtrl", function ($scope) {

    var template1 ='<div ><span >{{row.entity.name}}</span></div>';
    var template2 ='<div ><span >{{row.entity.age}}</span></div>';
    var template3 ='<div ><span >{{row.entity.address.house}}</span></div>';

    $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
            { field: 'name', cellTemplate: template1},
            { field: 'age', cellTemplate: template2},
            { field: 'house', cellTemplate: template3}
        ],
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
         $scope.grid1Api = gridApi;
        }
    };
    $scope.users = [
            { name: "Anup K", age: 10, 'address': {'house': '34','street': 'MG Road','city': 'Pune'} },
            { name: "Suresh Kumar", age: 30, 'address': {'house': '12','street': 'Brigade Road','city': 'Bangalore'} },
            { name: "Rohini Shah", age: 29, 'address': {'house': '18','street': 'AB Road','city': 'Mumbai'} },
            { name: "Mohan Alavala", age: 25, 'address': {'house': '50','street': 'Gulmohar Road','city': 'Delhi'} },
            { name: "Atul M", age: 27, 'address': {'house': '3','street': 'Charminar Road','city': 'Hydrabad'} }
        ];
    $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.users;
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .myGrid {
    width: 500px;
    height: 230px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="uigridApp">
    <h2>AngularJS UI Grid Sorting Example</h2>
    <div ng-controller="uigridCtrl">
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="myGrid"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfZW8.png)

There are three columns name, age and house. Sorting is working only for name and age column and not for house (since it is nested users->address->house)

How can I handle this scenario?
 Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

In `columnDefs` specify `field: 'address.house'`. It should do the trick. Your final `columnDefs` will look like this:

```
columnDefs: [
    { field: 'name', cellTemplate: template1},
    { field: 'age', cellTemplate: template2},
    { field: 'address.house', cellTemplate: template3}
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is working If I have data in JSON format. But How to handle same situation If data is  Javascript Object & It has nested array of objects & one of the column is rendering nested object variable. 
e.g. I have template like  
         var template3 ='<div ><span >{{row.entity.address[index].house}}</span></div>',  
 what value should I assign to field in columnDef.  
 I tried  address[index].house, but its not working . 
 Note : I dont want to convert Javascript object to JSON.

Comment: Provided you want to sort your `House` column by the first address from the nested array, you can set `field: 'address[0].house'`. But in case you need to show all the addresses and sort by `house` the whole data set, then the only way to achieve that is flattening your data set.